# Combining SUM and INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I am using the following formula to grab a number from each PivotTable and sum the result.

```
=SUM(Index(A1,Match(D1,G1:G50,0)),(Index(W1,Match(Y1,Z1:Z50,0))
```

The formula is then copied down to match the name in A1 down to A100. The problem is that in some cases there is a match for the name for only one of the two PivotTables, and the result isn't calculated. In cases where the name is found in both PivotTables, it calculates without a problem.

How do I specify that if there is no match it should just treat it as a zero and continue on?

Comment: `IFERROR` - so in this case `=SUM(IFERROR(Index(A1,Match(D1,G1:G50,0)),0),IFERROR(Index(W1,Match(Y1,Z1:Z50,0)),0))`

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered through comments, hence porting the answer here behalf of **Demetri**

Note: Additionally added cell freeze option in formula by using "$"

Use the below function to worn on it.

```
=SUM(IFERROR(Index($A1,Match(D$1,$G$1:$G$50,0)),0),IFERROR(Index($W1,Match(Y$1,$Z$1:$Z$50,0)),0))
```